# New line character as part of the String

Tags: java, string, newline

I've got the problem creating String looking as follows:

```
"SSR LANG SA  HK1/EN;S7;P1\n"+
```

Code that does that should append \n as part of the string + quote + append string literal + actual new line literal:

```
javaFormattedText.append("   \""+ tokenizer.nextElement() + "\\n\"+\n");
```

The output String should look:

```
"SSR LANG SA  HK1/EN;S7;P1\n"+
```

But it looks:

```
"SSR LANG SA  HK1/EN;S7;P1
\n"+
```

Therefore java complains about unclosed string literal.

The purpose of doing it is generating test classes dynamically and those contain a lot of text information that needs to be java formatted strings.

How can achieve the target?

**UPD**

Solved the problem by doing this:

```
String line = (String) AIR_textTokenizer.nextElement();

line = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: what does `tokenizer.nextElement()` return?

Comment: Plain String, in my case: SSR LANG SA  HK1/EN;S7;P1

Comment: I think `tokenizer.nextElement()` is returning a new line after `SSR LANG SA  HK1/EN;S7;P1`. A possible option here is to replace the `\n` in the string with blank/space before doing `tokenizer.nextElement()`.

Comment: Try to pass a string literal directly, and see the difference : _javaFormattedText.append("   \""+ "SSR LANG SA HK1/EN;S7;P1" + "\\n\"+\n");_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `tokenizer.nextElement()` is probably returning a trailing new line. To remove that:

```
String str = tokenizer.nextElement();
if (str.endsWith('\n')) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
javaFormattedText.append("   \""+ str +"\\n\"+\n");
```

Comment: U are right figured that out 30 sec before your answer by doing: line = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""); And it worked. How come I am not able to see new lines when printing the plain text on the console?

Comment: Even if it would then how would you know? :)

Answer (score -1):

If you watn to add line separator use: System.lineSeparator();

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Code with what u suggested looks as follows javaFormattedText.append("   \""+ tokenizer.nextElement() + "\\n\"+"++System.lineSeparator()); And has exact same affect as my version.

Comment: Still,you better use the lineSeperator method.

Comment: But it is not what I was asking. Thanks for the advice.